# Dell Vostro 3700 Laptop Screen Back light Not Working - but its not the screen

Tags: laptop, display, dell-vostro

I replaced the screen two times on a Dell Vostro 3700 laptop.  It's a LED backlight screen supposedly  (LTN173KT01-C09).    When I put in the first replacement, it DID work at first, but only lasted a couple weeks before it went dark.    The video is working if you shine a light inside.   So what else would cause the LED backlight not to work?   The video cable looks ok at least on the screen side, and what I can see going in to the case.   I have not opened the main housing yet.    An external monitor works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of diagnostic protocol, you have to check every centimeter of the screen wiring harness... All the way to the connector on the motherboard.  Until you have verified the health of the cable and connector, as well as the connection to the board, you can't go further.

Comment: Even though I did not see anything physically wrong with the cable,  I went ahead and replaced it.  It worked, so far so good!